# Obfuscate css and html in blade template

Tags: laravel-4, obfuscation, laravel-blade

Is there a way to make life harder on users which trying to copy my html source in laravel blade templates?

Is it possible to obfuscate blade template without javascript? I know about this for example `{{ HTML::obfuscate('me@gmail.com') }}` it is working with emails..